# I can't transfer data between angular components. I can't Decode data transfer between angular components

Tags: angular

I want to transfer data between two components in my Angular project, I use @input for this, but when I navigate to the component I want to transfer with navigateByUrl, the data I send to the component is reset, how can I fix this?

```
Code ;
Child Component :
  @Input() isModelist : boolean

parent Component : 
            <sample-measurement-table [isModelist]="true"></sample-measurement-table>
```

Comment: let me understand little bit more. You have parent and child component. And you are passing data with NavigateByUrl that will reach to parent component. And child component is getting reset? is that the problem?

Comment: @NirmalyaRoy Yes, this is exactly the problem. The data goes to the component, but when I press my button and go to the component with navigateByUrl, the page is reset because it refreshes.